# Linking from one wiki page to a page in a different library, same site

Tags: 2010, wiki, pages

How can I link pages together from different libraries?

I have a wiki site with multiple libraries on Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 3):

The standard, simplest way of doing this is to use built-in wiki functionality:

1. Type `[[` then wait for the drop-down menu which should show other pages in the same library at the end of the menu 2 options  -Lists and Views.
2. Use keyboard Arrows <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> to select `LISTS`(*very important: DO NOT USE MOUSE as the menu is quite Sensitive*)
3. Press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key. This should show a list of all libraries/lists (if you have more than 8, start by typing a part of the target Library name which shall filter out only those matching).
4. Again, once selected, ONLY VIA Arrow keys, press <kbd>TAB</kbd> again to see all Items from the library, which could other pages.

Once done, simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it will automatically close with `]]` while putting the actual link to the selected page. It should look something like

> [[Name of page|link text]]